# Static date in the last column

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am looking to do an IF THEN statement that will help me put a date into the U Column. However, I am not sure how to go about it.

```
Sub()
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Set rng1 = Selection.SpecialCells("U").xlBlanks
   If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then rng1.Value = Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy") 
End Sub
```

When I run this code I receive a run-time error '1004'. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: which row(s) in column U do you want to test? Also, it's better to post *actual* code you have (even if it doesn't work) as opposed to psuedo-code. Actual code shows us the specific problem more clearly ;)

Comment: I am trying to test all the rows that don't have a current date attached to them already. So, when new data is inserted the system will see that it will need todays date and put it in column U.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to find the range of cells that actually has data, because you don't want to check rows of column U where the entire row itself is empty. So assuming the last possible row of data can be found in column A, you can use this to set the search range.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'qualify sheet, change name as needed

    Dim lRow as Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then, you can set the search range to be from Row 1 to `lRow`, assuming the data is in a contiguous range left-to-right, top-to-bottom starting in A1. (The On Error statements are necessary, since Excel will throw an error if blank cells do not exist in the range).

```
    Dim rngSearch as Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngSearch = .Range("U1:U" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
```

If the range is set then you can enter values into the entire range at once (which you had in your code above).

```
    If Not rngSearch is Nothing Then rngSearch.Value = Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")

End With
```

Comment: Great @zach123. Please mark as answered so others know going forward.